# Compare and replace values in MS Access

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to do a match between two fields in the same table. If value A is null and value B is not null, replace value value A with value B. If value A is not null and value B is null, no change to the table.......？
I want to compare the whole column of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use column names as both l-values and r-values in an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    b = a, a = NULL
WHERE  A IS NOT NULL AND b IS NULL;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a61f/1)

Comment: Thank you. May I know if I want to compare 4 columns versus 4 columns, how would the code be like?

Comment: @JeffFoo I don't understand the question. If you have a different question, please post a new question, with the full example, table structure, etc.